# Multiple textareas with CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I try to set CKEditor 5 to more than one `<textarea>`, but only the first one works.

Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/1.0.0-alpha.2/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea name="content0" class="editor" id="c0">This is some sample content.</textarea>
<textarea name="content1" class="editor" id="c1">This is some sample content.</textarea>
<textarea name="content2" class="editor" id="c2">This is some sample content.</textarea>
<script>ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('.editor'));</script>
```

And here is the result:
[image]

Why only first?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first matched element. You need [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/1.0.0-alpha.2/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea name="content0" class="editor" id="c0">This is some sample content.</textarea>
<textarea name="content1" class="editor" id="c1">This is some sample content.</textarea>
<textarea name="content2" class="editor" id="c2">This is some sample content.</textarea>
<script>
var allEditors = document.querySelectorAll('.editor');
for (var i = 0; i < allEditors.length; ++i) {
  ClassicEditor.create(allEditors[i]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: but if I dont know amount of editors? I want use one script for all elements '.editor' at my site

Comment: But that's exactly what I've shown you. `document.querySelectorAll('.editor')` gets all elements with `editor` class and then we loop through them, creating a CKEditor instance for each one.

Comment: they should really have an in-built way to do this if they chose to not integrate with jquery. just my 2 cents. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use foreach instead of for loop like the @Wizard's answer

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-init-plugin="ckeditor"]').forEach(function (val) {
    ClassicEditor
        .create(val, {
            toolbar: ['bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList'],
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(event) {
        var editor = event.editor;
        editor.on('change', function(event) {
            // Sync textarea
            this.updateElement();
            for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor' + i].on('change', function() 
            { CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor' + i].updateElement() });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```